# Preload all the pages of a website in the background - possible solutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I've found many preloaded plugins to preload elements of a page but what I would like is a pre-loader acting in the background (while the user is browsing the current page) and that would load all the pictures, etc. of the other pages of my website (+/- 10 pages).
I read an article where someone suggested to put the other pages in 1px by 1px iframes. I guess that would work but i doubt google would like it.
Is there any better solution? thanks

Comment: Not sure to understand the downvotes...

Answer (score 0):

Visitors to your site won’t necessarily be looking at every page and therefore they will be wasting bandwidth downloading content they don’t need.

You could try http://instantclick.io/ which begins preloading a page once a link is hovered.